# Multi Word tags do not work in shopify product filtering

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

I have a shopify site where the collections pages have filters based on tags. The actual filtering works just fine, but as part of the UX, there is a checkbox that becomes checked once the filter link is clicked (it just toggles a class on the link). The issue I am having is that only the filter links that have "Multiple Words" do not show that checkbox being checked (It is not toggling the class needed to do that). I tried doing a quick fix with an .onClick event with jQuery, but since the filter links are ajax loaded after being clicked, it does not work. I believe that the class toggle is being done with liquid, but I am not sure. If anyone has a solution to this, I would really appreciate it!

Here is the liquid code:

```
            <div class="basel-price-filter basel-scroll">
       {%- assign check_tag_hide = true -%}
       <ul class="show-labels-on swatches-normal swatches-display-list basel-scroll-content">
          {%- assign key = block.settings.key_2 | downcase  -%}
          {%- assign key_2 = block.settings.key | downcase  -%}
          {%- if cat_array.size > 0 and block.settings.use_auto_filter_tag -%}
                {%- for i in cat_array -%}
                   {%- assign i = i | downcase  -%}
                   {%- if i == key or i == key_2 -%}
                         {%- for t in tag_arr -%}
                            {%- assign t = t | downcase  -%}
                            {%- assign t_split = t | split:'_' | first -%}
                            {%- if i == t_split -%}
                              {%- if current_tags contains t -%}
                                 {%- assign tag_value_remove = t | remove: i | remove: '_' -%}
                                 {%- capture cat_link_remove -%}{{ tag_value_remove | append: '&nbsp;x' | link_to_remove_tag: t }}{%- endcapture -%}
                                 {%- assign get_link_remove = cat_link_remove | split:'href="' | last | split:'"' | first -%}
                                 <li class="sc-layered-nav-term">
                                   <a class="current-state" href="{{get_link_remove}}">{{ tag_value_remove | upcase }}</a>
                                   {%- if block.settings.use_tag_countdown -%}{%- include 'tag_countdown',tag:t -%}{%- endif -%}
                                </li>
                              {%- else -%}
                               {%- assign tag_value = t | remove: i | remove: '_' -%}
                               {%- capture cat_link -%}{{ tag_value | link_to_add_tag: t }}{%- endcapture -%}
                               {%- assign get_link = cat_link | split:'href="' | last | split:'"' | first -%}
                                <li class="sc-layered-nav-term">
                                   <a href="{{get_link}}">{{ tag_value | upcase }}</a>
                                   {%- if block.settings.use_tag_countdown -%}{%- include 'tag_countdown',tag:t -%}{%- endif -%}
                                </li>
                              {%- endif -%}
                             {%- assign check_tag_hide = false -%}
                           {%- endif -%}
                          {%- endfor -%}
                   {%- break -%}
                   {%- endif -%}
                {%- endfor -%}
         {%- elsif tags.size > 0 -%}
              {%- for t_o in tags -%}
                 {%- assign tag = t_o | downcase  -%}
                 {%- if current_tags contains tag -%}
                     {%- assign tag_value_remove = tag | remove:key_2 | remove:key | remove: '_' -%}
                     {%- capture cat_link_remove -%}{{ tag_value_remove | append: '&nbsp;x' | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}{%- endcapture -%}
                     {%- assign get_link_remove = cat_link_remove | split:'href="' | last | split:'"' | first -%}
                     <li class="sc-layered-nav-term">
                       <a class="current-state" href="{{get_link_remove}}">{{ tag_value_remove | upcase }}</a>
                       {%- if block.settings.use_tag_countdown -%}{%- include 'tag_countdown',tag:t -%}{%- endif -%}
                     </li>
                      {%- assign check_tag_hide = false -%}
                  {%- else -%}
                    {%- for t_d in tag_arr -%}
                       {%- assign t = t_d | downcase -%}
                       {%- if t == tag -%}
                         {%- assign tag_value = t | remove:key_2 | remove:key | remove: '_' -%}
                         {%- capture cat_link -%}{{ tag_value | link_to_add_tag: t }}{%- endcapture -%}
                         {%- assign get_link = cat_link | split:'href="' | last | split:'"' | first -%}
                         <li class="sc-layered-nav-term">
                             <a href="{{get_link}}">{{ tag_value | upcase }}</a>
                             {%- if block.settings.use_tag_countdown -%}{%- include 'tag_countdown',tag:t -%}{%- endif -%}
                          </li>
                          {%- assign check_tag_hide = false -%}
                        {%- endif -%}
                     {%- endfor -%}
                  {%- endif -%}
               {%- endfor -%}
          {%- endif -%}
   </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery fix that I tried, but that did not work:

```
          $('.main-page-wrapper').on('click','.sc-layered-nav-term a',function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('current-state');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved by assigning a new group to the current filters, and using a string to replace spaces with dashes in order for the tags to be found. Then changed the if statment:

```
{%- assign tag = t_o | downcase  -%}
{%- assign tag_key = t_o | downcase | replace: ' ', '-' -%}
{%- if current_tags contains tag_key -%}
```